# Groovy - expanding list into closure arguments

Tags: groovy, closures, dynamic-programming

Is it possible to have a list and use it as an argument for a closure signature that instead several variables?  The reason is that I have to call a closure from java code, and the java code won't know what variables the groovy closure needs.

This is better served with an example.

Say I have a 'closure repository', where each closure might have different signatures.  EG:

```
closures = [
    closureA: { int a, String b ->
        a.times {
            System.err.println(b);
        }
    },
    closureB: { int a, int b, String c ->
        (a+b).times {
            System.err.println(c);
        }
    }
]
```

Then I've got a method that I'm exposing to my java code to call these closures:

```
def tryClosureExpansion(String whichClosure, Object ... args) {
    def c = closures[whichClosure]
    c.call(args)     // DOESNT COMPILE !
}
```

And it Java I'd call this method like this:

```
// these calls will happen from Java, not from Groovy
tryClosureExpansion("closureA", 1, "Hello");
tryClosureExpansion("closureB", 1, 5, "Hello more");
```

See above on the line that doesn't compile.  I feel like groovy is 'groovy' enough to handle something like this.  Any alternative that might fly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Does:

```
c.call( *args )
```

Work? Not at a computer atm to test it

Comment: It should work. Also, just using the method call syntax should work too: `c(*args)`; but you may take advantage of the `call` method and use the safe navigation operator in case the closure does not exist: `c?.call(*args)` (of course, this depends on your design, maybe throwing an exception on that case may be a better idea).

Comment: Thanks Tim, that did it.  I'm wondering where this is documented?  I checked the Operators and Collections pages, and they mention the spread operator, but this is a bit different as it's not specifying an action on the list.  @epidemian - thanks, I'm actually going to check ahead of this call and throw an exception.

Comment: @RoyTruelove It's called the `Spread Operator`.  It's used to apply something to multiple entries in a COllection, or in this case expand the list [into multiple parameters](http://jroller.com/aalmiray/entry/another_gem_from_groovy)

Comment: Thanks Tim!  Very useful.  Saved my rear.

Comment: If you get an error about a multiply operation, make sure your method call has parentheses attached. ;-)